# How do I switch arrow types in Made in Abyss?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

If I'm carrying multiple types of arrows, how do I switch which type of arrow I have equipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch your equipped arrow, bullet, or fishing bait type by pressing up or down on the d-pad. (If you are using keyboard, press 1 or 3 instead)

[image: Control options for Made in Abyss]